# probability that a symmetric simple random walk of length 100 step will hit 20 and -20, and finish exactly at 0.

Tags: probability

The way I approached this is by first using conditional probability:
$ P(A,B,C) = P(A|B,C) P(B,C)$

where events A,B are the hitting $\pm 20$, and C is ending at 0 after 100 steps.

I can use the formula for the maximum of a walk:
$ P(M_n \geq r, S_n=b) = P(S_n=2r-b) \quad (\text{if} \ \ r>b)$

which exactly describes $P(B,C)$ where $r=20,n=100,b=0$

but I'm having trouble calculating $P(A|B,C)$

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: does the order in which it hits $\pm20$ matter?

Comment: no, the order does not matter.

Comment: I think you can use a reflection principle for this problem. In the maximum formula you gave, the idea is that two kinds of walks are in bijection: (1) those for which $M_n \geq r$ and $S_n = b$, and (2) those for which $S_n = 2r - b$. This is because we can take the first kind of walk and reflect its steps after the first time it hits $r$; then the new walk ends at $2r - b$ instead of $b$. Similarly, when we take the second kind of walk and perform the same reflection, we get the first kind of walk. For this problem, you can reflect twice; at the first times the walk hits $+20$ and $-20$.